# Division in Haskell for Numeric class

Tags: haskell, division

I am trying to define a function `toVal :: (Num a) => (Fraction a) -> a`. The function takes a fraction and evaluates its numeric value. But since the function uses division, I can do the following since division is defined by different functions on the subclasses of `Num a`:

```
data Fraction a = Constant a
    |Rational{numerator :: (Fraction a), denominator :: (Fraction a)}


toVal1 :: (Integral a) => (Fraction a) -> a
toVal1 (Constant a) = a
toVal1 (Rational num den) = (toVal1 num) `div` (toVal1 den)

toVal2 :: (Fractional a) => (Fraction a) -> a
toVal2 (Constant a) = a
toVal2 (Rational num den) = (toVal2 num) / (toVal2 den)
```

Is there a way I can combine the two functions so that I can have a generic function `toVal :: (Num a) => (Fraction a) -> a`?

Comment: Hey @Carsten thanks for your response. Isn't Fractional a subclass of Num?

Comment: I totally missed the point there **sorry** - to answer your question: you can combine those if you create a type-class around `toVal` and then declare instances almost exactly like you did here - right now I cannot test it and I admit that I did not think it through but it should work ... I think

Comment: btw: did you look at [`Ratio`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html) - it seems that you try to implement something very similar

Comment: In `Ratio`, the concrete type is constrained to be Integral. Here, it mixes Fractional and Integral. I believe that it is more related to  [generic number types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generic_number_type), with all standard caveats that apply.

Comment: You might find [this question I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35745191/211160) and its answers to be useful.  *(I'm trying to learn the language, and asked that after seeing your question and trying out some things myself.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since `Num` has no notion of division, or, to say it in C++ terms, because there's no `dynamic_cast<...>` in Haskell.

You could introduce your own typeclass:

```
class HasDivOp a where
  divOp :: a -> a -> a

instance HasDivOp Int     where divOp = div
instance HasDivOp Integer where divOp = div
instance HasDivOp Double  where divOp = (/)
instance HasDivOp Float   where divOp = (/)
```

And then have a single function that takes the correct `divOp`:

```
toVal :: (Num a, HasDivOp a) => (Fraction a) -> a
toVal (Constant a)   = a
toVal (Rational a b) = toVal a `divOp` toVal b
```

An alternative way to reduce the code duplication is to add an additional function:

```
divG :: (a -> b) -> (a -> a -> b) -> Fraction a -> b
divG p _ (Constant x)       = p x
divG p f (Rational num den) = f (divG p f num) (divF p f den)
```

That is, for fixed `a`s and `b`s tell `divF` how to combine two `a`s into a `b`, or how to transform an `a` to a `b`, you can reduce two `Fraction a`s into a single `b`. In all your cases `a = b`, so we can define another helper:

```
divF :: (a -> a -> a) -> Fraction a -> a
divF = divG id
```

Now we can define both `toVal1` and `toVal2` in terms of `divF`:

```
toVal1 :: Integral n => Fraction n -> Fraction n -> n
toVal1 = divF div

toVal2 :: Fractional n => Fraction n -> Fraction n -> n
toVal2 = divF (/)
```

That being said, both `toVal` and `toVal1` lead to interesting behaviour on integral numbers:

```
toVal1 (Rational (Rational 2 3) (Rational 2 3)) = 0 :: Int
```

But `x div x` should be 1 for any `x /= 0`. If you preprocess your integral `Fraction`s this problem won't occur:

```
rationalDiv :: Integral n => Fraction a -> Fraction a -> Fraction a
rationalDiv (Constant a  ) (Constant c  ) = Rational a       c
rationalDiv (Constant a  ) (Rational c d) = Rational (a * d) c
rationalDiv (Rational a b) (Constant c  ) = Rational a       (b * c)
rationalDiv (Rational a b) (Rational c d) = Rational (a * d) (b * c)
```

Note that this needs a `Num` instance for `Fraction` due to `*`. That way you have the most control about the actual division and just need to transform the elements at the end:

```
toVal3 :: Integral n => Fraction n -> n
toVal3 = divF div . divF rationalDiv
```

Which correctly leads to `1` in our upper example. But to get back to the topic: no, you cannot use only `Num` as a constraint, you need to use another one that actually has a notion of division.