# Can "overloading" via FlexibleInstances return different types, or match on typeclasses?

Tags: haskell, overloading

I'm curious about what kind of "overloading" can be accomplished in Haskell's type classes via "FlexibleInstances".

As a simple test, here is a case of an AdjusterType datatype.  It defines an `adjust` operation that will add a different amount to its value based on whether it contains an Integer or a Double:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Adjustable a where
    adjust :: a -> Double

data AdjusterType a = Adjuster a
    deriving Show

instance Adjustable (AdjusterType Integer) where
    adjust (Adjuster a) = fromIntegral (a + 20)

instance Adjustable (AdjusterType Double) where
    adjust (Adjuster a) = a + 0.04
```

That much works as expected:

```
Prelude> adjust (Adjuster (1000 :: Integer))
1020.0

Prelude> adjust (Adjuster (3 :: Double))
3.04
```

**Is it possible to make the Integer version of `adjust` return an Integer, and the Double version return a Double?**

Generalizing the signature of `adjust` and removing the `fromIntegral` on the integer case doesn't work:

```
class Adjustable a where
    adjust :: Num n => a -> n

instance Adjustable (AdjusterType Integer) where
    adjust (Adjuster a) = a + 20
```

This produces an error saying that "n" is a rigid type variable that doesn't match Integer:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘n’ with actual type ‘Integer’
    ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for adjust :: Num n => AdjusterType Integer -> n
Relevant bindings include
    adjust :: AdjusterType Integer -> n
In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘a’
In the expression: a + 20
```

**What type was it expecting here that Integer isn't matching...or would no type actually work and it's just a weird error message?**  *(n is lowercase, so presumably it knows it's not a datatype)*

Type constraints in the instance specifications also don't appear to participate in the matching resolution:

```
instance Integral i => Adjustable (AdjusterType i) where
    adjust (Adjuster a) = fromIntegral (a + 20)

instance RealFloat r => Adjustable (AdjusterType r) where
    adjust (Adjuster a) = a + 0.04
```

So these act like duplicates, as if they were both `Adjustable (AdjusterType x))`.  The constraint only applies after the resolution is done.

**Is there any way to provide an overloaded behavior like above to a type class, or must it always be to a specific instance?**

Comment: You want to use [type families](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the Integer version of adjust return an Integer, and the Double version return a Double?

You can make the `Adjustable` type class accept two type parameters instead of one, so it will know what's inside the `AdjusterType`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Adjustable f a where
    adjust :: f a -> a
```

Then the instances should be:

```
instance Adjustable AdjusterType Int where
    adjust (Adjuster a) = a + 20

instance Adjustable AdjusterType Double where
    adjust (Adjuster a) = a + 0.04
```

And some results from ghci:

```
> :set +t

> adjust (Adjuster (100 :: Int))
< 120
< it :: Int
> adjust (Adjuster (100 :: Double))
< 100.04
< it :: Double
```

> What type was it expecting here that Integer isn't matching...or would no type actually work and it's just a weird error message?

The return type of `adjust` is of type `forall n . Num n => n`, a polymorphic type with a single constraint `Num`, so your function returning a concrete type won't type check. Wrap your function with `fromIntegral` will solve the problem since `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`.

> Is there any way to provide an overloaded behavior like above to a type class, or must it always be to a specific instance?

If you expect the function to behave differently for every distinct type, yes you have to add an instance for each. You may add some default behavior though, by restricting the type parameters of the class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Extract f where
  extract :: f a -> a

class (Extract f, Functor f, Num a) => Adjustable f a where
  adjust :: f a -> a
  adjust = extract . fmap (+20)

data AdjusterType a = Adjuster a
  deriving (Functor)

instance Extract AdjusterType where
  extract (Adjuster a) = a

instance Adjustable AdjusterType Int where
-- don't have to write any code here
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response!  Do you have anything to add regarding how the "type families" affect this in terms of what they offer, regarding what Bakuriu's answer demonstrates?

Comment: @HostileFork Type family is crucial, even necessary once you want the return type of `adjust` to follow some rules instead of simply matching the input type, e.g. `adjust :: AdjusterType Int -> Double` and `adjust  :: AdjusterType Double -> Int`, in that case type family is usually either the only solution or the best regarding type inference, code style etc. For your current use case it's a possible (maybe more extensible) solution among others.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using type families, in particular associated data types, is the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Adjustable a where
    type Elem a :: *
    adjust :: a -> Elem a


data AdjusterType a = Adjuster a
    deriving (Show)


instance Adjustable (AdjusterType Integer) where
    type Elem (AdjusterType Integer) = Integer

    adjust (Adjuster a) = a + 20

instance Adjustable (AdjusterType Double) where
    type Elem (AdjusterType Double) = Double

    adjust (Adjuster a) = a + 0.04

main = do
    let x = Adjuster 1 :: AdjusterType Integer
        y = Adjuster 1 :: AdjusterType Double
    print $ adjust x
    print $ adjust y
```

It compiles and the output is:

```
21
1.04
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the example.  Okay, of the questions asked...this appears to be able to address *"Is it possible to make the Integer version of adjust return an Integer, and the Double version return a Double?"*, this accomplishes that without parameterizing Adjustable with another type.  Is this required for that, or is there something like `adjust (Adjuster a) = a + (20 :: Integer)` which could do the same trick?  That doesn't work (complains about Double, even though it's the Integer case)...is the purpose of this to fix that?